# Is it alright to share the abstract of my article while it is under review

Tags: copyright, abstract

I am in contact with another researcher and want to share the direction of my current research for a possible opportunity. Would it be okay to share just the abstract and author list of my article with them. The article is still under review and not accepted/published yet.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, until you sign away your copyright after acceptance for publication, the article (in full) is yours and your co-authors.

And, even after you sign away the copyright, you normally get back a license that would permit such local sharing in any case - especially for collaboration purposes.

As user Snijderfrey notes in a comment it would be proper to get agreement from co-authors.

Comment: For *unpublished* work, I would like to be informed as a co-author. I would not object to the kind of sharing OP has in mind, of course.

Comment: @Snijderfrey, yes, thanks. Edited.

Comment: After it's published it's _public_. Anyone can read it. There might be an unlikely  small ethical problem sending a copy if the published version is behind a paywall,

Comment: @EthanBolker, I'm pretty sure the license covers such things.

Answer (score 0):

What is copyrighted is the concrete work. Ideas as such aren't copyrightable. You are free to share your insights with others.

In any case, publication is precisely to disseminate ideas, I'd be very surprised if the journal objects to sharing e.g. preliminary versions or preprints (but look up their policies or ask if in any doubt).